# Jenkins backup and restore jobs and upgrade plugin and jenkins version

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins for build configurations on ubuntu system. Recently asked some questions on jenkins about installation and backup all.
1)How to take back up of jenkins job and restore them.
2)How to configure same set of jobs on different server of jenkins
3)What are the precautions or steps involved in jenkins Up gradation along with plugin up gradation.
4)How to make sure that jenkins starts automatically when system is restarted.
5)where can i find the build log for the jobs.
Thanks in advance for your answers. please let me know if anyone knows any other jenkins interview questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer briefly because you are going to have to learn the basics on your own. there are a lot of good manuals about Jenkins and How-To, and Stack Overflow is not the place for it.

1. Regarding [1, 2, 3] - On the Master Jenkins you have several folders. You can use any source control to store the "Jobs" folder containing the config.xml of the jobs, the "config.xml" file under the root folder that holds all the Jenkins master configuration of tools, security, etc. and use a file repository as Nexus to store your "Plugins" folder. in order to restore your Jenkins just move and extract those folder back to your Root folder of the Jenkins master. To upgrade Jenkins to a new version just download the new war and replace your existing one.
2. Regarding [4] - Jenkins is usually defined as a service - you can read online how to start a service automatically after a reboot in Linux [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples)
3. Regarding [5] - Logs for the jobs are on the master, but you can always use the "console output" in the job's page to view them.

Comment: Thank for the information. I have one more question. I updated one plugin to latest version and found some issue with installation and i want to go back to previous version of that plugin. How can i do that and what are the precaution that we need to take.

Comment: I would suggest provisioning a staging environment to test such changes :) either way, downgrading plugin to an older version which you tested on the same environment poses no risk, although it's not good practice. You can downgrade it using the Manage Plugins -> installed tab, where a downgrade option is available. if not - uninstall the plugin, download the hpi with the desired version and install it manually